# padding in md5 hashing algorithm

Tags: md5, padding

i would like to know padding process in md5 algorithm detail.

Comment: Padding is rather straight forward, as pointed out by Jeff, see RFC1321. The padding is always made of one bit set to 1 and the rest all zeros, in quantity sufficient to bring the message length modulo 512 minus 64  (the reason for 64 is keep room for the message length).  Anyway, are you asking question about the padding "rules" or the cryptographic reasons behind it (and behind this trick with a one and all zeros), or maybe yet something else (java-related?) ?  Please specify.

Answer (score 2):

The MD5 algorithm (including padding) is described in [RFC 1321](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1321.txt), section 3.

Do you need more detail on implementation, though?  I noticed your question is tagged 'java' but you didn't ask about anything Java-specific...

Comment: The wikipedia article about cryptographic padding has an example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29#Bit_padding